# less compiler not work with extract function

Tags: less

after many and many test i can not understand why "extract" or "at" function in less not work.
i have tried use those functions in my less file, but without success.

**file.less**

```
@list: apple, pear, coconut , orange;
.test{
  color:extract(@list,0);
}
@backgroundcolors:{
  dark: #AA2222;
  blue: #AA3333
}
@colors: {
  bg-dark: #2f353b;
  bg-blue: #3598dc
}
each(@backgroundcolors, {

  .color-@{key}{
    background-color: @value;
    color: @index;

    a:at(@colors,bg-blue);
    b:at(@colors,"bg-blue");
    c:extract(@colors,0);
  }
});
```

**file.css**

```
    .test {
      color: extract(apple, pear, coconut, orange, 0);
    }
    .color-dark {
      background-color: #AA2222;
      color: 1;
      a: at(, bg-blue);
      b: at(, "bg-blue");
      c: extract(, 0);
    }
    .color-blue {
      background-color: #AA3333;
      color: 2;
      a: at(, bg-blue);
      b: at(, "bg-blue");
      c: extract(, 0);
    }
```

in my result .test contains not only index 0, but any others item in @list. in sencod attempt i have trie use "at" or "extract" in a each loop, but always in this case i have failed. Now i use lessc 3.9.0

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes for the [`extract`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract) function start from 1:

```
@list: apple, pear, coconut , orange;

a {
  value: extract(@list, 1); // value: apple
}
```

Using of [maps](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature):

```
@colors: {
  dark: #2f353b;
  blue: #3598dc;
}

a {
  color: @colors[dark]; // color: #2f353b
}
```

No idea what does `at` mean.